# @ in Function definition in Matlab

Tags: matlab, function

I was just browsing through a code and I found the following line :

```
other_function(@(t)(xx(t,g)))
```

where other_function,xx are already defined functions and g is already defined.

Here is the code for xx

```
function [val]=xx(x,y)
val=x+y;
end;
```

SO now I am unable to understand the meaning of @(t)(xx(t,g))

Comment: What happens in other_function? The handle of the function `xx` is passed to `other_function`.

Comment: It's used like this so you don't have to pass `g` into every `other_function` call. If `g` should always be input the same, then this syntax turns `xx` (a function of 2 inputs) into `other_function` (a function of 1 input with the same functionality as `xx`).

Answer (score 0):

It is a function handle. It is useful to pass functions as parameters. You can find more in the [MATLAB documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html)

Just an example: suppose you have a simple function

```
function y = computeSquare(x)
y = x.^2; 
end
```

than you can compute an integral in this way:

```
q = integral(@computeSquare,0,1);
```

In your example: `other_function` declares as an input parameter a function `t` and another parameter called `g`.